# Thurston measure of Dehn-Thurston ball center at a multi curve

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, teichmuller-theory

Given a surface of genus $g$ with $n$ singularities, and a decompostion of pair of pant $P=(p_1,...,p_{3g-3+n})$ one can give coordinate (called Dehn-Thurston coordinate) on the space of lamination $\mathcal{ML}$ $$
C_{P}: \lambda \mapsto (i(\lambda,p_i),t(\lambda,p_i))_{i \in [1,...,3g-3+n]}
$$
If one pick a real $\iota >0$, a lamination $\gamma$, we will call Dehn-Thurston ball the set $$
B_{DT}(\gamma,\iota)= \{ \lambda \in \mathcal{ML}, \|C_{P}(\lambda)-C_{P}(\gamma)\|_{\infty} \leq \iota \}
$$

**Question:** Now given a geometry $X \in \mathcal{T}$ (where $\mathcal{T}$ is the Teichmüller space of the surface) can we compute $$
\mu_{Th}(X) (B_{DT}(\gamma,\iota))
$$
Or if this to complicate, at least give an asymptotics when $\iota \to 0$?

---

An easy case is when $\gamma = 0$. Then it is well know that for any $A \subset \mathcal{ML}$ measurable $$
\mu(X)(\iota A) = \iota^{6g-6+2n} \mu(X)(A)
$$

So $\mu(X)(B_{DT}(0,\iota))=\iota^{6g-6+2n}\mu(X)(B_{DT}(0,1))$

---

What we could try is to come back from the definition $$
\mu_{Th}(X) (B_{DT}(\gamma,\iota)) = \underset{M \to \infty}{\lim}\frac{1}{M^{6g-6+2n}} \# \{ \delta \in \Gamma, \delta / M \in B_{DT}(\gamma,\iota)\}
$$
Where $\Gamma$ is the set of the simple closed curves, and try to find a bijection between  $\{ \delta \in \Gamma, \delta / M \in B_{DT}(\gamma,\iota)\}$ and $\{ \delta \in \Gamma, \delta / M \in B_{DT}(0,\iota)\}$ to find the same conclusion as the previous part.